# Sonata You have requested a non-existent service "request"

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm using sonata admin and mediabundle in symfony 3.2 application.

composer.json

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.x-dev",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "4.x-dev",
"sonata-project/media-bundle": "4.x-dev",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.x-dev"
```

I generate mediabundle as said in doc

> sf3 sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle

Then in my entity I add a relation with media entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $image;
```

I configure sonata media as said in doc:

```
sonata_media:
    db_driver: doctrine_orm
    default_context: default
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/
```

and then added it to my admin

```
->add('logo', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false), array(
                    'link_parameters' => ['provider'=>'sonata.media.provider.image'],
                    'label'    => 'Logo',
                    'context'  => 'default',
                    'required' => false,
                ))
```

When i try to add an image i get this error:

> You have requested a non-existent service "request". Did you mean one
>   of these: "data_collector.request", "monolog.logger.request",
>   "request_stack", "router.request_context",
>   "sonata.intl.locale_detector.request_stack",
>   "validate_request_listener"?

So i try to understand where it use $this->container->get('request') but i find out that in sonata code it use something like:

```
if ($this->container->has('request_stack')) {
            return $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        }


return $this->container->get('request');
```

That seems to be right.
So why i get this error?

Comment: Using development versions is not recommended at all, why are you doing that?

Comment: Because when i create the project symfony 3.2 is also in dev and i've got a lot of problem with dependencies.

Comment: If symfony 3.2 is also in dev, don't use it. The dev version is not meant for you, it's meant for people who want to contribute a bc-breaking change to the next version.

Comment: I use symfony 3.2 because it will be release in November.
By the way i solve the issue changing the version of sonata in my composer but it need some change to work with symfony3.
Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Consider reporting the issues you have with sf3 compatibility, or even contributing some fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this answer to people who don't want to use sonata classification bundle with sonata media bundle (like me) so have to use 4.x-dev.
I make a [commit](https://github.com/iskyd/SonataMediaBundle/commit/e663c1ff275db951407c8fe3c4ef2f698d837d5f) to make it compatible with symfony3 (seems).
Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

The request service no longer exists with Symfony3.

You must use the request_stack service instead

Comment: Never advise `dev-master` versions, these are meant for development.

Comment: You don't say ?

Comment: If you read my question you can see:
if ($this->container->has('request_stack')) {
            return $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        }


return $this->container->get('request');

Comment: This is because the Sonata code isn't Sf3 friendly. That's why I advised to try the dev-master version, just in case it could temporarly fix your issue.

Comment: I can assure you that if you do $this->container->get('request') in SF3 you will have an exception.
As you can see here :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md

"The request service was removed. You must inject the request_stack service instead."

Comment: Yeah but you're never supposed to reach this piece of code because you are supposed to have a `request_stack` service available

Comment: Why was he downvoted? He seems correct. $this->get("request"); is crashing in my controller in symfony 3.4 LTS